# Subir scroll após mudar de view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view, rolamento

Estou utilizando **angular** no meu sistema

Estou mudando as **views** com o comando `$state.go('main.shops.cart.success');`

Mas o *problema* é que quando *muda* a **view** o **scroll** continua em baixo. Gostaria que quando ele mudasse a **view** o **scroll** fosse para o topo da página.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Precisamos ver a composição do se código para existir um ponto de partida.

Comment: O que você precisa ver? @Bsalvo

Answer (score 1):

Será que o que você quer fazer é isso: `window.scrollTo(0, 0)`?

De acordo com essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007296/6882194

Acho que você pode usar:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```